# How can I store the results of a Windows command prompt command to a file?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to store Windows command prompt data (like the results of a "dir" command) in a text file with (preferably) or without C++?

Comment: You can use `dir >somefile.txt`

Comment: As others had pointed out, it is easy to do that without c++. What do you mean by 'with c++'? Do you plan to execute the cmd.exe from your c++ code?

Comment: yes I want to execute through c++ program!

Comment: Your question said with _or without_ c++. Now you say 'with' and all the answers are wide of the mark. You should be clearer in your questions.

Comment: You could use CreateProcess() and pass the argument that you need to execute exactly as you would type it on command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cmd redirect operator > for that.
c:\ execute.exe > out.txt
Out put file out.txt will get created in same folder as exe. If can also save output in different path.

Other commands which can help you.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490982.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In order to pipe the output of a command into a text file, append the command with `> filename.txt`. your final command would look like  `dir > filename.txt`

No C required!

**NOTE:** this will overwrite all data previously stored in filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use C++ at all. You can simply use command redirection operators.

the 2 useful commands in your case would be the `command > file.txt` write redirective and the `command >> file.txt` append redirective.